# Get selected value from rowlist and pass it to query string laong with page number in JqGrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

```
 I have a row list as [10,20,30] i want to pass the selected row list ie if (20 is selected ill pass that 20 as query string and retrieve the value). and also i want to select the page number too. What are the possible ways to achieve the selected value from row list and current page number and then pass the value to query string.
```

I tried  var Page=$(".ui-pg-input").val()
but it is not firing i think i am missing something out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done. By using the predefined session values in it